# How to pass a FLAG such as -DVERBOSE during a Bazel build command?

Tags: c++, c, build, bazel

I would like to do something like setting a macro name that activates portions of my code....

`g++ -DVERBOSE=1 main.cc`

during the Bazel build command:

`bazel build //myproj:main`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bazel build //myproj:main --cxxopt=-DVERBOSE=1`

Or, use the [`copts`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.copts) attribute in `cc_*` targets.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--cxxopt

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use copts outside a `BUILD` file? The docs dont hint it is possible.